# wordpress выдает предупреждения при использовании spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

Пытаюсь настроить автоматическую загрузку классов в плагине wordpress с использованием функции spl_autoload_register. Все подключается нормально, плагин работает, но wordpress генерирует предупреждения, относящиеся судя по всему не к моему плагину:

```
Warning: include(папка плагина/class-loco-hooks-loadhelper.php): failed to
open stream: No such file or directory in папка плагина\functions.php on line 8

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'папка плагина/class-loco-hooks-loadhelper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in папка плагина\functions.php on line 8
```

Функция автозагрузки классов:

```
function my_plugin_autoload($class){
    $file = str_replace('_', '-', strtolower($class));
    include (__DIR__.'/class-'.$file.'.php'); // та самая 8-ая строка

}
```

Comment: Ну Вы почитайте что Вам любезно пишут - нет такого файла, вот и ошибка. У Вас загрузчик неверно создаёт путь из класса. Или же просто файл там нет.

Comment: @other так судя по названию файла его и не может быть в моей папке - вопрос в том, почему wordpress его там ищет

Comment: Так Вы сами так прописали. Судя по всему, вызывается класс с названием типа `loco_hooks_loadhelper`, преобразуется и он ищется в папке `__DIR__`.

Comment: просто другой момент в том, что на одном виртуальном сервере со встроенной функцией __autoload - никаких проблем нет - вот что самое странное

Comment: Просто гляньте какой путь создаётся и смотрите где ошибка.

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться

Comment: Вообще на будущее используйте константу `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` и регистрозависиммое наименование, такое может происходить из за разницы платформ linux и windows у одного диретория разделяеться так '/' у другого так '\', ну и в linux пути регистрозависимы в windowse нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема возникает из-за того, что при использовании автозагрузки классов в плагинах wordpress загружаемые от плагинов классы попадают в общую очередь автозагрузки, и для избежания проблем в функции автозагрузки необходимо задавать проверку имен классов на соответствие шаблону:

```
function my_plugin_autoload($class){
    //проверяем наличие в имени класса контрольной строки
    if(strpos($class, 'my_class_prefix_') === 0){
        $class_dir = realpath(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $class_file = str_replace('_', '-', strtolower($class));
        include_once $class_dir.'class-'.$class_file.'.php';
     }
}
```